# Website performance: How to reduce difference in domContentLoadedEventStart and domInteractive time?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, optimization

We have recently done revamp of our one of the key pages. We have done following changes:

1. Moved rendering from client side to server side.
2. Made modular javascript (Created 8 Modular Javascript files. There were only 2 earlier, we have just made them modular so size is still the same. But they are all in different JS now so effectively 8 separate downloads instead of 2. We have not bundled as we are using HTTP2)

We are tracking our performance based on following metrics:- https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-dominteractive

We are observeing a spike in following timing: **domContentLoadedEventStart - domInteractive**

AFAIK by studying [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp), this is the time in which DOM is parsed after receiving first HTML byte. But I am clueless why it's showing an increase of 1 seconds after making above changes? The changes should ideally reduce this time as html is prepared from server. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you say, "Moved rendering from client side to server side" which would mean the server is now responsible for serving HTML instead of just data? That said, seems like your server is taking more time to respond.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: No, server response time is consistent and the difference here is time after first HTML byte is received. The server respose time is under 100 milliseconds while we see a spike here of around 1 second

Comment: Is the wait for 8 Javascripts instead of 2 the problem? Can you just merge them into 1, once, and confirm? I think it might the ping time for assets that increases causing the entire load time to be increased.

Comment: I understand that you are using HTTP2 but what I really mean is one of the JS might be taking longer to load?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think it should be a problem as we are on HTTP2 and JS is on CDN. Plus, we have not faced any such issue till now

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: Does JS download starts immediately after domInteractive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166635/discussion-between-akshay-khandelwal-and-maverick).